# custom newline style in environments

Tags: line-breaking, environments

I want to add something to each newline, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{mystuff}{dark magic goes here}{or here}
\begin{document}
\begin{mystuff}
first row
second row
\end{mystuff}
\end{document}
```

and I want Latex to render it like this:

```
first row -and this was added by mystuff environment
second row -and this was added by mystuff environment
```

How do I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henri Menke says, the `^^M` trick is risky, but it does work in a pinch. I edited this to use `\obeylines` (essentially equivalent and risky) which simplifies the code a little. I also removed the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` commands.  I altered the code slightly so that you can specify, on the fly, the text that is added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\def\specialccr{\mytext\newline}
\def\specialccr{\mytext\par}

{\obeylines
    \gdef\specialcr{\obeylines \let^^M=\specialccr}%
}

\newenvironment{mystuff}[1]{%
    \def\mytext{#1}%
    \parindent0pt
    \leftskip3em
    \everypar={$\bullet$\ }
    \par
    \noindent
    \specialcr}{%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{mystuff}{\ -- and this was added by mystuff environment}% <- % Necessar
first row
second row
third row
\end{mystuff}

\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

One final edit. The original used `\newline` which does not start new paragraphs. I substituted `\par` which in turn allows all sorts of interesting formatting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using an active end of line character `^^M`. This is **not** a good solution, but it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\def\special@cr{!\newline}
{\catcode`\^^M=\active%
    \gdef\specialcr{\catcode`\^^M=\active \let ^^M=\special@cr}%
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{mystuff}{\par\noindent\specialcr}{}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{mystuff}% You will want to suppress the ^^M here.
first row
second row
\end{mystuff}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image]